# List.of() method not found in spring boot application error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

1. I checked all imports they are correct the only error I am getting is while calling the `List.of()` method.

```java
UserDao user1 = new UserDao();
user1.setName("j");
user1.setUser_name("k");
user1.setPassword("l");
user1.setPhone("86632");
    
UserDao user2 = new UserDao();
user1.setName("j");
user1.setUser_name("k");
user1.setPassword("l");
user1.setPhone("86632");
```

2. Here the `of` method is not found in spring tool suite I am on `jre1.8`

```
List<UserDao> users = List.of(user1, user2);
Iterable<UserDao> itrb = userRepo.saveAll(users);
```

Comment: without use list.of method if used arraylist instead there is no issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade to Java9 to use `List.of` function, or use `Arrays.asList` instead.

Comment: code `import java.util.Arrays` can import `Arrays` object.

Answer (score 1):

`List.of` is introduced starting from Java 9. So that you have to upgrade your Java to make use of one.

Answer (score 1):

You need atleast Java 9 for using List.of() function
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#immutable